# cannot open map on android emulator even if I followed all steps

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-emulator

I have followed all steps to display a map on emulator through my android app but firsly when I add the google_play_service_lib, I have this problem : it is not affected to my project but to itself
[image]
and also when I put ok and I close the property window and I will open it after I find that : 
[image]

and after all that when I run the project the map doesn't open and I have an error :

```
    java.lang.nullPointer  in this line :
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

how can I fix this issue

Comment: Solution for the Library issue is: Library, eclipse and your workspace should be in same drive partition.

Comment: I don't have eclipse in the same partition, I will move it and try again

Comment: this issue is fixed, now I will test the emulator of SBerg413

Answer (score 1):

At the current time, you cannot run google maps on the defualt android emulator (at least not without jumping through a lot of hoops).  You'll need to either test on a device or use one of the custom emulators out there.

Here's a custom emulator that google maps apparently works one:

http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

For displaying Google Map on emulator,you should use target API level as GoogleAPI.then you can add google maps on emulator.

[image]

Comment: but me, I have just android 4.3 - API Level 18 in the dropdown menu

Comment: download it from SDK Manager